# jquery, replace html on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which is using a select list to jump around my site. This is currently using onclick window.location so user selects the page and presses go and it goes to that page.

I now need to add a small text box for the user to type in a code (say 123456) and then when they click go, it should go to the url selected, but with the [CODE] being the number entered in the box. I discovered jquery replaceAll so it gave me the idea to have this in the select html:

> http ://jumptothispage.com/parts/p[CODE]/edit
>
> http ://jumptothispage.com/jobs/j[CODE]/edit

When you press go, it would replace all [CODE] in that html with the code entered and then jump to that page selected, e.g.

> http ://jumptothispage.com/parts/p123456/edit
>
> http ://jumptothispage.com/jobs/j123456/edit

I am already using jquery on my site so makes sense to try and utilize that again. I'd appreciate a pointer and or other suggestions instead.

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Sorry -- really can't work out what you're trying to do. Could you try to edit the question? In particular, what do you mean by 'all the html with that form be updated'?

Comment: I hope my edit makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: Store the code in a cookie, so at least it's not visible to every person who looks at the URL bar.  Then in every `onclick`, fit it into the URL to send the user to the "right" page.

Or, have your select option's value literally read `CODE`, which your onclick interprets to mean "The user hasn't set the code yet."  When the user types in the code, store it in a variable (in the example below, `realcode`), and you can then do this:

```
$('select#navigation option').each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).attr('value', $(el).attr('value').replace(/CODE/, realcode));
});
```

Comment: Hi, the second option is sounding good although I think by setting it as the value I would lose the ability to have that code used in different pages? At the last count there are ten different urls which I need to give as options, all of which need a number in the middle of the url - I updated the question to make that clearer. I will attempt a go at trying this out and come back, thanks for dropping by!

Comment: Well, for the 2nd part, you could use `$(document).ready()` to *read* the window.location, and if the word CODE is present in the right place, then do the replacement shown in my answer, otherwise use the word CODE.